# rosserial custom message compilation problems

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated rosserial to 0.3.0, and as far as I can tell also updated everything else along with it.  I have a custom message defined and now my rosserial_arduino sketch won't compile.

The compiler was complaining about my message being an abstract type so I added const to the end of the serialize function definition.

When I use make_library.py to recompile the message it has an error about Header. I get
"roslib.msgs.MsgSpecException: sensor_state.msg: Header header is not a legal message type"

I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11894/rosserial-custom-message-compilation-problems/) by [electronic kiwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1356/electronic-kiwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED. My message definition file (.msg) had some Tab characters separating the type and the name.  When I removed those the message compiled, and then my sketch would compile.

---

Originally posted by [electronic kiwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1356/electronic-kiwi/) with karma: 16 on 2011-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0